# issue exporting path to spark home on ubuntu

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, python-3.6, ubuntu-server

I’m installing spark, and pyspark on my ubuntu server.  I’m trying to set my SPARK_HOME path on ubuntu server and I’m getting the error below.  Does anyone see what the issue might be?

code:

```
export SPARK_HOME='/home/username/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7'



export PATH$SPARK_HOME:$PATH
```

output:

```
-bash: export: `PATH/home/username/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7:/home/username/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin': not a valid identifier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH`

Missing equalTo..

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quickly, that did the trick!